# How to combine two data sets in Stata keeping only the overlapping variables?

Tags: loops, variables, stata

I'm trying to combine two datasets, say `data1.dta` and `data2.dta`, in Stata, keeping only the overlapping variables and I want to `drop` all variables that exist only in one of the two datasets.

My idea was to compare the two data sets with `cfvar`: with `return list` I get the output `r(both)`, `r(oneonly)` and `r(twoonly)`. And now I want to use the outputs `r(oneonly)` and `r(twoonly)` for a loop to `drop` all variables that are listed in `r(oneonly)` and `r(twoonly)`, something like:

```
for each v of varlist ??how to define the varlist??{ drop v }
```

Comment: How about `help mmerge`?

Comment: Also asked at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1318187-how-to-combine-two-datasets-keeping-only-overlapping-variables

Answer (score 0):

I know of no program `cfvar`; perhaps you mean `cfvars` (SSC), which turns out to be something I wrote. But that is redundant given recent versions of Stata. You can go

```
d using data1, varlist 
local v1 "`r(varlist)'" 
d using data2, varlist 
local v2 "`r(varlist)'" 
local both : list v1 & v2 
u data1 
keep `both'
```

Then you need to `merge` with `data2`: the syntax will depend on which variable(s) act as identifiers. Note the `keepusing()` option of `merge`.

I can't see that a loop is needed here.